# @RequestMapping regular expression

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make value atribute for spring @RequestMapping annotation to map url like this

```
/educationDistrict/308/action/resetAddressesForYear/1
```

and this

```
/educationDistrict/308/action/resetAddressesForYear
```

I'h have this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{repository}/{id}/action/{methodName:[A-z]*}{v:.*}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

but first url does not match.

I can't use multi value because of spring-hateoas
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/186

spring 4.1.5

Answer (score 5):

Add `/**` at the end of the URL mapping in `@RequestMapping`. And you can retrieve last part of the URL as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{repository}/{id}/action/{methodName:[A-z]*}{v:.*}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome(@PathVariable("methodName") String name, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String mvcPath = (String) request.getAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    int index = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(mvcPath, "/");

    System.out.println("Method name - " + name);        
    System.out.println("Rest of the URL - " + mvcPath.substring(index+1));

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("index");
    model.addObject("name", mvcPath);

    return model;
}
```

**Note:** I have used `StringUtils` Apache Commons to find the last index of `/`.