# Spring boot controller mapping covers resources - cannot access them, what can I do?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources, spring-boot

I have a controller mapped at

```
@RequestMapping("/{param}")
```

So when I try to access resources I cannot because it is interpreted as a call to this controller. Can I add a controller with some final mapping that will be like a proxy to the default resource handling controller?

In my case I really don't want to to be forced to do something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/something/{param}")
```

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have your root URL be parameterized this way.  What is your use case that you can't add a path like you said you don't want to do?

Comment: The website I'm creating will be editable when it comes to content and if an admin adds a section it will be immediately available at a given url. And to be honest adding something that is unnecessary just looks bad. And if I add a static mapping to some other controller it will always be available. So I was wondering if it's possible to create a proxy controller for the resources at /res for example.

Comment: It seems like you must have some sort of pattern to the content URLs as opposed to resources since I would also expect that the admin area has to have its own URL that is different.  Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160917/requestmapping-regular-expression and see if this gives you any ideas on something that can be used to classify your dynamic content.