# Can we pass dynamic value to @RequestMapping annotation of spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to map URL's in a dynamic way as follows,
consider that I am trying to access with different URL's

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/XYZ/Login.htm

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/PQR/Login.htm

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ABC/Login.htm

From the above URL's  I want to show different Login.htm page to the different user.
Here in above URL's there is only change in request of  XYZ, PQR and ABC and rest of all is same, So this will be handled at class level @RequestMapping annotation of the controller class as per my knowledge  .
If I manage to pass value dynamically to @RequestMapping  annotation so I think I can achieve what I want to .

Please, can anyone suggest me how can I get dynamically value in the @RequestMapping annotation? Or any other suggestion to get Different Login page when URL changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@RequestMapping regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160917/requestmapping-regular-expression)

Answer (score 6):

You can use path variable matching

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MyApp/{id}/Login.htm", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFoosBySimplePathWithPathVariable(
  @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return id;
}
```

See documentation:

- [RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)
- [PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply @Boaz. Can you please elaborate this means what should I pass a value for id as pathVariable?

Comment: @Robert, did you read the documentation that Boaz has provided? It will give you the answers.

Answer (score -3):

you used if else condition, URL's in a dynamic way as follows, if condition we request mapping we give any string direct correct jsp page otherwise go to else part point out 404 error.

```
  i want correct code....
```